# Getting parsing error with c++ plugin using macros

Tags: c++, msbuild, sonarqube, parsing-error

I have the following code in my `.cpp`:

```
STDMETHODIMP CChildFrame::raw_StateChanged(long _lIndex)
{
    return S_OK;
}
```

and I have the following code in my `.h`:

```
STDMETHOD(raw_StateChanged)(long _lIndex);
```

I am using build-wrapper with MSBuild.

When I am using sonar-runner analyser it gives me the errors:

Unable to parse file...

RecognitionException : Parse error at line...

Comment: Did you remember to #include `basetyps.h`?

Comment: Are you sure it matters considering it actually compiles?
And that build-wrapper is suposed to make me a file with the paths to the included code

Comment: From your description, you are seeing compiler errors. Did I not understand your post correctly?

Comment: I am sorry i'll edit the post. Those errors come from sonar-runner analyser command prompt.

Comment: When I get back to work tomorow, i'll post a screen shot of the command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The define _WIN32 is missing, I don't now why.
You need to add: sonar.cfamily.predefinedMacros=#define _WIN32.

Comment: The define is missing from the json from build-wrapper

Comment: So I add it where? in the sonar.properties?

Comment: Yes in the propertie file